# datetime converting sql incorrect result

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

Hi I have a problem with sql query datetime. My code is this:

```
datetime(DATASTRING,'unixepoch','localtime')
```

It return me this:

```
1982-11-24 12:06:56
```

Only year is wrong... How can I correct it with 2013?
Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the **data type** and **value** of `DATASTRING`?

Comment: Type is timestamp and value: 406984016

Comment: Are you using `SQLight`?

Comment: What makes you think that `406984016` represents the *number of seconds since 1970* for your desired date?  How was this number initially created?

Comment: I've found the explanation in another post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857185/2866409